# API Google Maps - Exceeded request quota

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google

Estou com um problema, quando crio um projeto no Google Maps e coloco a chave, depois de recarregar a página, alega o erro `You have exceeded your request quota for this API`. Porém criei meu projeto e API no mesmo minuto. O que devo fazer?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                  <head>
                    <title>Simple Map</title>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <style>
                      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
                       * element that contains the map. */
                      #map {
                        height: 100%;
                      }
                      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
                      html, body {
                        height: 100%;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                      }
                    </style>
                  </head>
                  <body>
                      <h1>dsadsadasd</h1>
                    <div id="map"></div>
                    <script>
                      var map;
                      function initMap() {
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                          center: {lat: -23.5745792, lng: -46.6235351},
                          zoom: 8
                        });
                      }
                    </script>
                    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzMklPLGCiJpHydazwhc5X1a1zN8iW_S4&callback=initMap"
                    async defer></script>
                  </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: O erro é bem explicativo: "You have exceeded your request quota for this API".

Comment: Entao mano... Eu comentei no inicio. Não é possivel atingir nenhuma quota pois eu criei agora e não publiquei nem utilizei o MAPA. Dei um f5 e apareceu esse erro...

Comment: Crie outra chave para ver se funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Você não deve ter ativado o faturamento na sua conta, [apenas o "embed map" é gratuito agora](https://mapsplatformtransition.withgoogle.com/calculator) (aquele que você usa com um iframe).

Para mais informações, visite [esta página de ajuda](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing), que dá informações sobre como proceder.

Comment: Ahhh sim, Em relação ao Embed Map é viavel? Parece o lugar certinho da coordenada?

Comment: É sim, aparece como no site mesmo. Você consegue experimentar neste link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start